# Having a hard time creating a function that displays all different combinations of n numbers (0<n<10)by ascending order

Tags: c, logic, combinations

I'm having difficulty finding the underlying logic for this. I know recursion would help however I don't know how to approach it. My difficulty lies when get dealing with sending/ printing the array on the base case. Everything I do I can only iterate the last digit and don't know how to go about the others.

If n is 2:

`$>./a.out | cat -e`

`01, 02, 03, ..., 09, 12, ..., 79, 89$`

If n is 3  things get harder:

`012, 013, 014, ..., 123, 124, ..., 134, 135,... 234, ..., 789$`

My code is far from working

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

bool is_consecutive(int arr[], int n)
{
    int last_value = 9;
    if ( n <= 0 )
        return false;
    while ( --n ) {
        if ( arr[n] != last_value-- )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void    ft_print_screen(int *t, int size)
{
        int i;
    
    i = 0;
        while (i < size)
    {
                ft_putchar(t[i] + '0');
        i++;
    }
        if (is_consecutive(t, size) != true)
        {
            ft_putchar(',');
            ft_putchar(' ');
        }
}

void    ft_print_combn(int n)
{
        int i;
        int tab[n];

        i = 0;
        if (n == 1)
                while (i < 10)
        {
                        ft_putchar(i + '0');
            i++;
        }
        while (i < n)
    {
                tab[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
        while (tab[0] <= (10 - n) && n > 1)
        {
                ft_print_screen(tab, n);
                tab[n - 1]++;
                i = n;
                while (i && n > 1)
                {
                        i--;
                        if (tab[i] > 9)
                        {
                                tab[i - 1]++;
                                tab[i] = 0;
                        }
                }
        }
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
    ft_print_combn(x);
}
```

Comment: First, clarify the problem. Your title indicates the goal is to create “all” combinations, but you show a partial list of combinations of two numbers and a separate partial list of combinations of three numbers. Does the function need to list all combinations or just those with a fixed number of numbers? If it has to list all combinations, what is ascending order? Is 09 before or after 012?

Comment: Second, once you have clarified, forget about C code and think about an algorithm to step through all combinations. Describe that algorithm to yourself.

Comment: Why are you using `write` to produce your output, as opposed to `printf` or `putchar` or any of the other buffered output functions from `<stdio.h>`?  You should normally never have to use `read` or `write` directly.

Comment: @TomKarzes Because it is going to be evaluated by an automatic grading system

Comment: How would using `putchar` affect that?

Comment: @EricPostpischil User pics a number from 1 to 9 and that's the size of the "array" of non repeating numbers. so if you pick 6 the first result is 012345 and the last one is 456789

Comment: @TomKarzes It automatically rejects your submission. I think the program reads from the console but I'm not sure

Comment: You can search StackOverflow for “[c] generate combinations” to find plenty of questions addressing this. There should be some among them that are suitable for what you need.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did I found none that addressed a variable length just fixed

Comment: What is the first combination of k digits? What is the last combination? If you have some combination, what is the next combination in ascending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that you should be able to adapt to your needs.  The code is conditionalized to use either stdio or bare `write` calls.  Just change the definition of `USE_STDIO` to `#define USE_STDIO 0` to make it use bare `write` calls (or simply remove the conditionlization).

Note that I used `int` rather than `size_t` for the string lengths, since they will never be larger than the character set size (i.e. 10), but you could of course use `size_t` if you prefer.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define USE_STDIO   1

void my_write(int len, char buf[len])
{
#if USE_STDIO
    printf("%.*s", len, buf);
#else
    write(1, buf, len);
#endif
}

void my_write_s(char *buf)
{
    my_write(strlen(buf), buf);
}

void show(bool first, int len, char buf[len])
{
    if (! first) {
        my_write_s(", ");
    }
    my_write(len, buf);
}

void end(void)
{
    my_write_s("$\n");
}

void gen_combs2(bool first, char *buf, int off, int m, char chars[m], int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        show(first, off, buf);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m + 1 - n ; i++) {
        buf[off] = chars[i];
        gen_combs2(first, buf, off + 1, m - i - 1, chars + i + 1, n - 1);
        first = false;
    }
}

void gen_combs(char *chars, int n)
{
    int m = strlen(chars);
    char buf[n];

    gen_combs2(true, buf, 0, m, chars, n);
    end();
}

int main(void)
{
    gen_combs("0123456789", 1);
    gen_combs("0123456789", 2);
    gen_combs("0123456789", 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `int m = strlen(chars);`  This will cause the compiler to output a warning because the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, NOT a `int`

Comment: @user3629249 No, it won't.  You can assign an integer type to a smaller integer type without a warning.  I *did* compile it.  Try it.  It implicitly casts it to `int` in this case.  I left off the cast because it was unnecessary.  I explained at the top that I didn't bother using `size_t` because it was unnecessary.